# Creating events on key stroke

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I want to create an event when every key stroke on the keyboard happened. So far I did this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class SpaceInvadors : Form
  {

    SpaceInvadors sInvaders;
    public SpaceInvadors()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      KeyStroke keyStroke = new KeyStroke();
      sInvaders=new SpaceInvadors(keyStroke);
    }

    public SpaceInvadors(KeyStroke keyStroke)
    {
      keyStroke.keyStroked += Form1_KeyDown;//How does that chaining to the event work?
      keyStroke.keyStroked += Form1_KeyUp;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyArgs e)
    {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Q)
      {
        Application.Exit();
      }
    }
  }
  public class KeyStroke
  {
    public event EventHandler<KeyArgs> keyStroked;
    public void Add(Keys key)
    {
        // I need to know how to obtain this key:
        KeyArgs keyAr = new KeyArgs(key);
        keyRisen(keyAr);
    }

    public void keyRisen(KeyArgs kA)
    {
        if (keyStroked != null)
            keyStroked(this, kA);
    }
}

public class KeyArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Keys KeyCode { get; set; }
    public KeyArgs(Keys key)
    {
        KeyCode = key;
    }
}
```

Also, how can I all the time listen to what keys were pressed, and not only once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your question

> "Also, how can I all the time listen
>   to what keys were pressed, and not
>   only once"

I see that you have already used Form.KeyDown event to close your game if 'q' was pressed:

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyArgs e)
        {
          if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Q)
          {
            Application.Exit();
          }
}
```

Ok you can add more keys to your method:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyArgs e)
    {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Q)
      {
        Application.Exit();
      }
      else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        spaceInvaders.MoveUp();
    }
```

For the chaining, I think that class KeyStoke manage playing interface. Because KeyDown event is used to determine what key was pressed. I advise you more learning to events and delegates.

Comment: it shows a line underneath keyDownEventArgs e. saying that i am missing an assemble?!?

Comment: i implemented your code and deleted mine.. but it shows a blue line underneath  KeyDownEventArgs... saying i am missing a reference,, do i need to add some using.. :(

Comment: Whenever you are missing a reference, google the exact class and method/property, and you will get the hierarchy of namespaces, which will help you get the right references and import statements. For instance if I google "form KeyDownEventArgs" I find the 3rd google entry is "KeyEventArgs Class (System.Windows.Forms" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I was writing the code without compiler, so that I accidentally wrote KeyDownEventArgs instead of KeyArgs

Comment: keyStroke.keyStroked += Form1_KeyDown;
could you explain to me how that chaining work.. say if i stuck to my code..would that event handler be triggered each time. i simply dont understand how this works..

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: You can also put the caret inside of the unknown type and press `Ctrl + .` and it'll import the using declarations for you.

Comment: Without more talking, create new "playing" project, add three buttons to the form, make the first print a messagebox "hello1" and the other one "hello2" when they're clicked, and then write in the third one button2.Click += this.button1_Click; now try to run and press button2, you will find that one message has appeared "hello2" now click button3 then click button2. Further help : http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2009/06/02/simple-c-events-example/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you are writing a game, The space invaders! :)
I dont think that this approach is good for game. The most appropriate and commonly used approach is to use [GetKeyboardState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646299%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. To achive good ingame results with this function you should create timer and check key states periodically. And I recomment you perform rendering also in timer routine.

If some reasons prevents you to use `GetKeyboardState` I will recomend you to use `PreviewKeyDown`

Comment: he provided me with an answer...phew.. i thought i had to write it all by myself